# php hook run functions

Tags: php

I am thinking of building some kind of "hook" function system. Basically a couple of functions that is run before the whole application start doing what it is suppose to do. I guess some kind of authentication would be proper to have as a hook. Check if the user is still logged in etc. There should also be some kind of priority order.

But how do I structure this kind of hook system? How do I initialize it?

I guess I would need some class to handle this for me. An add_hook and run_hooks method or something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[phpBB](http://phpbb.com), the open source bulletin board software, has a hook system you might benefit from looking into. Of course much of the code will be specific to phpBB's framework, but the basic idea would be the same, I think.

Answer (score 0):

I achieve this by using the `auto_prepend_file` directive of the php.ini file. In my case, it's `functions/init.php`, which does such things as connect to the database, get user data from SESSION, authenticate, update user's info if needed, etc. etc.. Sounds like just what you need.